# Struggling with the MINUS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I received this Oracle error when I try to do STAGE MINUS the GAME TABLE :
"ORA-01790: expression must have the same datatype as corresponding expression" I think I know where my problem is, but I don't know how to solve it.
I am trying to match "ntdo_stage.platform" with  " ntdo_game.platform_id".

And "ntdo_stage.esrb_rating" with "ntdo_game.esrb_rating_id". The thing is there are no platform_id and esrb_rating_id in the stage table, no platform_name and esrb_rating in the game table so I am not sure how to proceed.

The NTDO_GAME table has two foreign keys: 1) platform_id from NTDO_platform table
& 2) esrb_rating_id from NTDO_ESRB_RATING table

Below is my code:

```
 select distinct ntdo_stage.title, ntdo_stage.meta_score, ntdo_stage.user_score, ntdo_stage.link, 
  ntdo_stage.date2, ntdo_stage.platform, ntdo_stage.esrb_rating 
  from ntdo_stage  
  left join ntdo_platform 
  on (ntdo_stage.platform =ntdo_platform.platform_name)
  left join ntdo_esrb_rating
  on (ntdo_stage.esrb_rating =ntdo_esrb_rating.esrb_rating) 
  where title is not null 
  MINUS 
  select game_name, meta_score, user_score, link, release_date_comment, 
  ntdo_game.platform_id, ntdo_game.esrb_rating_id
  from ntdo_game
  inner join ntdo_platform 
  on (ntdo_game.platform_id = ntdo_platform.platform_id)
  inner join ntdo_esrb_rating 
  on (ntdo_game.esrb_rating_id = ntdo_esrb_rating.esrb_rating_id)
```

DDL for ESRB_RATING TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE ntdo_esrb_rating (
esrb_rating    VARCHAR2(10),
esrb_rating_id NUMBER NOT NULL
); 
ALTER TABLE ntdo_esrb_rating ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_esrb_rating_pk PRIMARY 
KEY ( esrb_rating_id );
```

DDL for PLATFORM TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE ntdo_platform (
platform_id   NUMBER NOT NULL,
platform_name VARCHAR2(55)
);

ALTER TABLE ntdo_platform ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_platform_pk PRIMARY KEY ( 
platform_id );

ALTER TABLE ntdo_game_developer
ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_game_dev_fk FOREIGN KEY ( developer_id )
    REFERENCES ntdo_developer ( developer_id );
```

DDL for the GAME TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE ntdo_game (
game_id              NUMBER NOT NULL,
game_name            VARCHAR2(55),
meta_score           VARCHAR2(10),
user_score           VARCHAR2(10),
link                 VARCHAR2(150),
platform_id          NUMBER NOT NULL,
esrb_rating_id       NUMBER,
release_date         DATE,
release_date_comment VARCHAR2(55)
);

ALTER TABLE ntdo_game ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_game_pk PRIMARY KEY ( game_id 
);
```

DDL for the STAGE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE "MASY_CW3956"."NTDO_STAGE" (
"META_SCORE" NUMBER(38,0), 
"TITLE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
"PLATFORM" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
"DATE2" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
"USER_SCORE" NUMBER(38,1), 
"LINK" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
"ESRB_RATING" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
"DEVELOPERS" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
"GENRES" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE (INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

THANK YOU!!

Comment: When posting code, put at least 4 blanks at the front of each line so the display treats them as code.  Compare your columns one-by-one for the SQL before the minus and after the minor. The columns must be in the same order and of the same type.  (number, character, date). Minus is an Oracle specific feature that includes null values in the comparison. If both values are null, the record is eliminated, but if either is not null, the record is kept.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of these 2:

`ntdo_stage.platform` in the fist query

`ntdo_game.platform_id` in the second

first is `VARCHAR2`, while the second is a `NUMBER` and you get inconsistent types.